# Who is the voice actress for the Terran adjutant from the first Starcraft?

Tags: starcraft

What is her name? Was her voice used in any other video games?

Comment: Stop closing it, we have lots of these!

Comment: Reopening to match http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/123224/23

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [IMBD](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217061/fullcredits), [Tiffany Hayes](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1225676/) is the voice actress for the Adjustant in SC1.

Furthermore, Tiffany Hayes has voiced acted for other games, all by Blizzard.

- [Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warcraft_III:_Reign_of_Chaos)
- [Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warcraft_III:_The_Frozen_Throne)
- [Diablo II as Charsi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_II)

Comment: Have you ever encountered some similar voice? And I also have troubles with searching Charsi from diablo 2.