# Who is the voice actress for the Terran adjutant from Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

What is her name, and has her voice been used in any other video games?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1037854/), the voice actress for the adjutant is [Julianne Buescher](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0003925/?ref_=tt_cl_t9).

Her voice is used in many movies and games spanning from Mulan to Star Wars the Old Republic.

Some notable video games she voice acted for are

- Guild Wars: Nightfall as Zerak/Additional Voices
- Guild Wars 2 as Faolain
- XCOM: Enemy Unknown as Soldier
- The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim as Female Altmers (voice) / Galathil - Dawnguard DLC
- Endwar